# vhdl Relational Operations

Tags: vhdl

Please I need help, I am trying to clip my value between +2048 and -2048 but this are in std_logic_vector i.e. ("111111111111100000000000000000000000" and "000000000000100000000000000000000000"), I am from a software background and I think that is why am having this issue, I have attached a snippet of my code

```
  --Saturate the output to -2048 to +2048

saturate1:process (x1,x2)
--variable sum, tmp :std_logic_vector(WWidth downto 0);
begin
    y11 <= x1+x2;

if y11 >= "000000000000100000000000000000000000" then
   y <= "000000000000100000000000000000000000";
elsif y11 >= "111111111111100000000000000000000000" then
   y <= "111111111111100000000000000000000000";
else
   y <= y2fullwidth;
end if;
end process saturate1;
```

y11,x1,x2 and y are all type std_logic_vector.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i) `"000000000000100000000000000000000000"`is not 2048 in binary. It's 16,772,216.

ii) You appear to be doing maths. Therefore, I would recommend using the `numeric_std` package and using type `signed`.

iii) You also need to divide your process into two. You cannot drive signal `y11` and then sample it later in the same process. (It will not be updated until the process suspends). If this is a surprise to you (rather than just being a typo), you need to find out more about how VHDL works.

If you use type `signed` then the comparison operators (`<=`, `>=` etc) are *overloaded* to work with types `signed` and `integer`:

```
y11 <= x1+x2;

saturate1:process (y11)
--variable sum, tmp :signed(WWidth downto 0);
begin    
  if y11 >= 2048 then
     y <= 2048;
  elsif y11 <= -2048 then
     y <= -2048;
  else
     y <= y2fullwidth;
  end if;
end process saturate1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Taylor, I was able to solve it using a variable, your method will not work it giving the same error as I have before but I appreciate the effort.